# I want to design an OTP Screen with EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, one-time-password

I am planning to design an OTP screen with 6 EditTexts so I have implemented TextWatcher in all editTexts. So it is going forward to each editText and i also implemented logic for going backward based on the editText length but if user enters wrong otp and if user goes on that particular editText on click of delete key from keyboard it is going to previous editText but it should not go back to previous editText  instead it should remain in the same editText.

```
private void setEventsForEditText() {
   editFirstOTPDigit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
       @Override
       public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
       }

       @Override
       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
           if (charSequence.length() == 1) {
               editSecondOTPDigit.requestFocus();
           }
       }

       @Override
       public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
       }
   });

   editSecondOTPDigit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
       @Override
       public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

       }

       @Override
       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
           if (charSequence.length() == 1) {
               editThirdOTPDigit.requestFocus();
           } else {
               editSecondOTPDigit.requestFocus();
           }

       }

       @Override
       public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

       }
   });

   editThirdOTPDigit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
       @Override
       public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

       }

       @Override
       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
           if (charSequence.length() == 1) {
               editFourthOTPDigit.requestFocus();
           } else {
               editSecondOTPDigit.requestFocus();
           }
       }

       @Override
       public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

       }
   });

   editFourthOTPDigit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
       @Override
       public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

       }

       @Override
       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
           if (charSequence.length() == 1) {
               editFifthOTPDigit.requestFocus();
           } else {
               editThirdOTPDigit.requestFocus();
           }

       }

       @Override
       public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

       }
   });

   editFifthOTPDigit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
       @Override
       public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

       }

       @Override
       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
           if (charSequence.length() == 1) {
               editSixthOTPDigit.requestFocus();
           } else {
               editFourthOTPDigit.requestFocus();
           }
       }

       @Override
       public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

       }
   });

   editSixthOTPDigit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
       @Override
       public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

       }

       @Override
       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
           if (charSequence.length() == 1) {
               buttonVerifyOTP.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               hideKeyboard();
           } else {
               editFifthOTPDigit.requestFocus();
           }
       }

       @Override
       public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

       }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this but you can try following:

Create some flag say

```
         private boolean isWrondOtp;
```

set this to `true` after OTP validation

and your textwatcher will look something like this

```
editSecondOTPDigit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            if (charSequence.length() == 1) {
                editThirdOTPDigit.requestFocus();
            } else {
                if (!isWrondOtp)
                    editSecondOTPDigit.requestFocus();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
```